Filing a Provisional Application for Two Inventions with Overlapping Inventors
I am looking to file a provisional patent application for a piece of hardware I have created and an application that utilizes said hardware. The hardware and application have overlapping joint inventors, but there are more joint inventors for the hardware that did not participate in the application invention. Can we file a US provisional application to include two inventions with all of the inventors and later on divide it into two non-provisional applications (with two different sets of inventors) claiming the priority of the same provisional application?

You could file one provisional application listing all inventors who contributed to anything inventive disclosed. An alternative that might serve you all better would be to write the description you plan to write that explains both aspects but file the same content twice, with the correct  respective inventors listed. The only additional effort or cost is the small filing fee. Read on for the actual issue which is list of applicants, not inventors.
If you might use the application(s) to get priority for a latter EPO application, for example, the identity of the applicant(s) will be more crucial than the inventors.
The applicant is the owner of the priority right. It could be a company you all work for or an entity you create and each assign your rights to. Also the applicants can be the same as the inventors list. However that will cause a problem if you later want to rely on priority at the EPO and possibly other jurisdictions.
The EPO requires the provisional be for the same inventions by the same person. That means the same owner of rights, or assignee of the owner of rights. If you file one provisional with applicants a, b and c and later b and c file an EPO application claiming priority to it then it will not be valid unless person a had assigned rights to either b or c. Or they could all assign rights to company D (or also D’). This assignment needs to happen before the EPO (or PCT) application.
MIT lost some rights regarding an important EPO application for CRISPR for this reason - See https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=4f70cb39-5efe-4b79-bed0-d77235be99a9
You might look at this issue as one of many complicated, non-intuitive topics can mess up your rights.

Thank you for the very helpful advice!
